# Javascript library to generate typical sounds

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I am interested in playing sounds of digits and letters in javascript.

I know how to play audio files in javascript, however I would like to know if any of you know any library or something with which you can just generate sounds that you want. I only need to be able to play individual letter and digits.

I realise that I could make files for every digit and letter and than play them when I desire, however I would like to know if a more elegant solutions exists.

Answer (score 1):

> any library or something with which you can just generate sounds

Sure: the standard [AudioContext](https://marcgg.com/blog/2016/11/01/javascript-audio/) and [Tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/) can generate at a low level. However,

> I only need to be able to play individual letter and digits.

That raises the same issues as with full words: What voice speaks these? Using what language/dialect? There are synthesis tools that offer a selection of voices and can generate/play a soundfile from an arbitrary string, like the mostly-supported [SpeechSynthesis API](https://usefulangle.com/post/98/javascript-text-to-speech). The voices vary though, and "elegant" can mean many things - a call to a synthesis library may look elegant to the programmer, yet produce an uglier sound. For such a limited set of numbers/digits, you may find prepared sound files more natural:

- [VoiceXML](https://evolution.voxeo.com/library/audio/prompts/)
- [random blog](http://www.theblog.ca/mp3-audio-files-alphabet)
- many more out there.